# Share OpenGL textures between two rendering threads?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, memory-optimization

I have an interface rendering to a GLSurfaceView, but at some point I launch another rendering thread in order to be able to render a part of the interface (just a couple of textures) at a much larger scale and then write them as an image file to the sd card. I wonder if and how it's possible to use the large textures I already loaded into the GUI rendering thread when I start another renderer with the purpose to write to disk?

Currently I have a very bad workaround, that is I keep the bmp in memory after I loaded the texture and then when I launch the write-to-disk renderer I just create a new texture from that bitmap. But apparently this is both time-consuming and memory-consuming when I feel it really shouldn't be necessary since the bitmap actually already is somewhere in the GPU loaded as a large texture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared Contexts. When you are creating the context for the second thread, pass the first context as the shared_context parameter. Then, you can access the textures in the second thread using the same handles as in the original thread.